# Type parameter issue in Scala with generic function

Tags: scala, generics, polymorphism, type-parameter

I'm trying to come up with a generic function (toBitSet) using type parameter T.

```
 def toBitSet[T:Integral](x:T, valueBitwidth:Int, filterBitwidth:Int, bigEndian:Boolean = true, shift:Int = 0) = {   
    BitSet((for (i <- 0 to (valueBitwidth - 1) if (((x & 0xFF) >> i) & 1) == 1) yield (i + shift)): _*)
  }
```

byteToBitSet and shortToBitSet functions are specializaton of the generic function.

```
  def byteToBitSet(x:Byte, filterBitwidth:Int, bigEndian:Boolean = true, shift:Int = 0) = {
    toBitSet[Byte](x = x, valueBitwidth = 8, filterBitwidth = filterBitwidth, bigEndian = bigEndian, shift = shift)
  }
  def shortToBitSet(x:Short, filterBitwidth:Int, bigEndian:Boolean = true, shift:Int = 0) = {
    toBitSet[Short](x = x, valueBitwidth = 16, filterBitwidth = filterBitwidth, bigEndian = bigEndian, shift = shift)
  }
```

However, Scala doesn't understand the operators (>>, &, ==, +) on type T to show an error message. I specified that `T` is Integral type, but it doesn't work.

[image]

How to solve this issue?

Comment: With such declaration you introduce an implicit parameter for your method of type `Integral[T]`. Scala's analog for `<T extends SomeType>` is `[T <: SomeType]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type signature
`def func[T: Integral](arg: T) = {}`
is actually a syntactic shorthand for:
`def func[T](arg: T)(implicit ev: Integral[T]) = {}` ("ev" is often chosen as the name for this "evidence" argument.)

The [Integral trait](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.math.Integral) outlines what operations you then use on elements of type `T`. Example: addition is `ev.plus(t1, t2)`

If you `import Integral.Implicits._` then you can use the more natural infix notation: `t1 + t2`

Unfortunately, the Integral trait doesn't include bit-wise operations like `&` and `>>`.

If you can modify your algorithm to use only those available ops you'll get the function you're after.